# Perl: parse hex-encoded string into array with regex

Tags: regex, perl, hex

I'm quite new to Perl development, and I'd like to perform a following task:

My script receives hex-encoded string as command-line param. Then I must decode this string and write it to output file like a C++ array with initialization from data given. For example:

`perl myscript.pl DEADBABEDEADBEEF`
and the output something like

`const boost::array<char, 8> MyArray = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBA, 0xBE, 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF };`

What is the right way to do this with Perl regex? Of course, I could perform it in loop with substrings, but I believe that there should be more elegant way.

EDIT: the input string is of fixed length.

Comment: What about Split/Map? Unless you are sure that your input string is of fixed length I doubt that regexp would be a good choice.

Comment: Yes, in this case I'm sure that my input string will be of fixed length. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
my $hex = "DEADBABEDEADBEEF";
my @a = map "0x$_", $hex =~ /(..)/g;
```

How it works:

First, `$hex =~ /(..)/g` in list context captures all 2-character substrings (the `/g` flag means global match). Then `map()` takes the list and transforms it to another one, using the `"0x$_"` expression for each element of the first list (`$_` here is an alias for the element).

See also [perldoc -f map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).

Comment: Thanks, your script is working. But could you please explain me the details? What is happened there, and what is the ',' (comma) between the operation? As I said, I'm quite new to Perl. :)

Comment: @Haspemulator: That's quite a tall order. Try `perldoc -f map` to get documentation for the map function, and `perldoc perlre` to get documentation for regular expressions.

Comment: Great solution, but it might be better to limit the two digits retrieved from the string to legit hex digits. ie, `my @a = map "0x$_", $hex =~ /([\da-eA-E]{2})/g;`, no?

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
my $input = $ARGV[0];
die "Fouled up input" unless $input =~ /^(?:[0-9A-F]{2})+$/i;
my $bytes = length ($input) / 2;
print "const boost::array<char, $bytes> MyArray = {";
while ($input =~ s/([0-9A-F]{2})//i) {
    # print $input # to see how this works, see comment.
    print "0x$1, ";
}
print "};\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct. But the second answer is correct, too. I'm not sure for whom should I vote. :)
And I have a question about your code: why in statement `$input =~ s/([0-9A-F]{2})//` you left second argument of s/// empty? What does this mean in this context?

Comment: It just deletes the first two characters each time. Put a `print $input` in the loop and you'll see how it works.

Answer (score 4):

How about unpack?

```
print join ",", unpack("(A2)*", "DEADBABEDEADBEEF");
```

Correction - you'd need a map to prefix each element that unpack returns with a "0x"

```
print join ",", map { '0x' . $_ } unpack("(A2)*", "DEADBABEDEADBEEF");
```